# structured variables pass to method becomes zero?

Tags: c#, variables, struct, unity-game-engine, local

unity c# global struct variable treated like local surprised but need to seek advise. in START:

```
struct ST{ public float f; public bool b_toProcess;}ST st;
st = new ST(){b_toProcess = true};
```

in Update:

```
if(st.b_toProcess) process(st);
```

somewhere in the same .cs:

```
process(ST st){
    Debug.Log("f:" + st.f); // 0
    st.f += 0.1f; if( st.f > 5){b_toProcess = false;}
    Debug.Log("f:" + st.f); // 0.1f
}
```

but process run never-ending !!!!
the logs showed that f was always 0 on start of each and subsequent iteration and after += was 0.1f thus never greater than 5. By right it should be accumulative on each iteration.
Question is: how come the st.f is always at 0 on each iteration. only local variable will be treated that way but that was passed in as a struct variable.

please some1 advise.
thanks.

Comment: You should read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664472%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

my psychic debugging powers are telling me that you expect your *struct* to behave like a reference type.

in c#, *structs* are value types.

---

When you call `process()`, the whole *struct* is copied, not just the reference. Anything you change in the *struct* will **not** be reflected in the *struct* in the calling method.

---

If you make it a *class* instead, then it **will** behave like a reference type.

you can also use the `ref` keyword

```
process(ref ST st)
{
   ...
}
```

and call it like this

```
if(st.b_toProcess) 
    process(ref st);
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is change your struct to class.

To explain why this will fix the problem. The difference between a struct and a class is a struct is an actual chunk of memory that is copy-ed around when it is put into a method. So when you modify a struct in a method you are changing a copy of it, not the original. With a class, it is created as a single chunk of memory in one place and when you pass it between methods you a passing a reference which in essence says go here for this data. So any modification to it is made on the same chunk of memory and is visible anywhere you reference that class.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to think of classes being allocated as a _"single chunk of memory"_.

Comment: I know it's not accurate but it works for illustrating the point here(possibly)

Comment: Agreed, for the `ST` class above it's ok